# Tor suggested packages

Tags: packages

Very hard to trust Tor, when no functioning install package exists. No install..I've done 25+...ever results in a nice clean install that doesn't result in unanswered questions.

Latest install attempt generates the following message during install:

aptSuggested packages:
  mixmaster torbrowser-launcher tor-arm apparmor-utils obfs4proxy

What is one supposed to do with these? If the install routine generates the message, why is it not covered somewhere in the FAQs?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you change your question to explain what OS you’re using, how you’re trying to install it, and the point at which the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Generally with "suggested" packages you can safely ignore them

They are just packages that may be useful to you if you installed Tor

If you want to install **recommended** packages run (assuming you're on a Debian based distro or it has apt, otherwise refer to your package managers documentation):

```
apt install <packagename> --install-recommends
```